# Azure Streaming Analytics input/output

Tags: python, azure, azureservicebus, azure-stream-analytics

I implemented a very simple Streaming Analytics query:

```
SELECT
    Collect()
FROM
    Input TIMESTAMP BY ts
GROUP BY
    TumblingWindow(second, 3)
```

I produce on an event hub input with a python script:

```
...
iso_ts = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).isoformat()
data = dict(ts=iso_ts, value=value)
msg = json.dumps(data, encoding='utf-8')
# bus_service is a ServiceBusService instance
bus_service.send_event(HUB_NAME, msg)
...
```

I consume from a queue:

```
...
while True:
    msg = bus_service.receive_queue_message(Q_NAME, peek_lock=False)
    print msg.body
...
```

The problem is that I cannot see any error from any point in the Azure portal (the input and the output are tested and are ok), but I cannot get any output from my running process!

I share a picture of the diagnostic while the query is running:
[image]

Can somebody give me an idea for where to start troubleshooting?

Thank you so much!

## UPDATE

Ok, I guess I isolated the problem.
First of all, the query format should be like this:

```
SELECT
  Collect()
INTO
  [output-alias]
FROM
  [input-alias] TIMESTAMP BY ts
GROUP BY
  TumblingWindow(second, 3)
```

I tried to remove the `TIMESTAMP BY` clause and everything goes well; so, I guess that the problem is with that clause.

I paste an example of JSON-serialized input data:

```
{
  "ts": "1970-01-01 01:01:17",
  "value": "foo"
}
```

One could argue that the timestamp is too old (seventies), but I also tried with current timestamps and I didn't get any output and any error on the input.

Can somebody imagine what is going wrong? Thank you!

Comment: What does Azure portal's monitoring page say, do you see input events and were there any errors? Also, was there anything in the operation logs?

Comment: No, I can't see nothing! it is like there is no event at all. This is strange, because I fixed 2 bugs in body encoding and timestamp format and they were signalled. So I guess that the input was read by the topology...

Comment: Do you know if in `FROM Input TIMESTAMP BY ts` the string `Input` should match some user defined name? For example, the input alias?

Comment: The string Input should be the name of the input. When you say " it is like there is no event at all". Do you mean input or output or both? What about input errors?

Comment: My input alias was `Input` and now I turned it to `input` with a lower case "i". I don't know why, but it seems that something has changed... Now I activated the monitoring stuff and I am updating the question.

Comment: Vignesh what do you mean with "the name of the input"? Do you mean input alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that my question was a duplicate of [Basic query with TIMESTAMP by not producing output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859156/basic-query-with-timestamp-by-not-producing-output).

So, the solution is that you cannot use data from the seventies, because streaming analytics will consider that **all the tuples are late and will drop them**.

I re-tried to produce in-time tuples and, after a long latency, I could see the output.

Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the Service Bus queue from Azure portal for number of messages received?