# Multiple input streaming analytics is not sending output even though Test gives output

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

My Inputs are Blob and eventhub and output is Azure Storage Table

EventHub:

```
{"Time":"2017-05-14T06:41:26.2630811","PowerDC":5642.45849609375,"AccelX":0.011730000376701355,"AccelY":0.0048699378967285156,"Pressure":9.0,"PartitionKey":"718a6ebf-aea0-4b4b-bb68-9ad5e9697164"}
```

Blob:

```
{"PartitionKey":"1","RowKey":"1","Timestamp":"2017-02-16 19:27:42.7994902 +00:00","InstallTime":"2017-02-16 19:27:42.5010225 +00:00","Location":"Test","Site":"Test","UUID":"718a6ebf-aea0-4b4b-bb68-9ad5e9697164","UninstallTime":null}
```

I have this query, when i run through sample and test it gives me output, but it does not send any output to the Azure storage table.

Query:

```
SELECT UR.PartitionKey as PartitionKey, 
maxpressure=50, 
max(EH.AccelX) as MaxAccelX , 
max(EH.AccelY) as MaxAccelY,  
Avg(EH.Pressure) as AvgPressure, 
DateAdd(hour,-8,max(EH.Time)) as maxtime

INTO OutputToTable
FROM FromEventHub EH TimeStamp by Time 

join UnitRecordBlob UR on EH.PartitionKey = UR.UUID 
Group by TUMBLINGWINDOW(mi,1), UR.PartitionKey
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859156/basic-query-with-timestamp-by-not-producing-output Got the solution. Thanks

Comment: If it is resolved, please have a try to add an answer that will let communities easily to search. [Answered in a question edit and converted to a community wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the)